# Is it possible in Python to construct a one-liner RETURN statement with a main IF condition that is a "gateway" for other conditions to check?

Tags: python, if-statement, return, conditional-statements

I'll try to make it clearer with an example code:

```
def is_opposite(string_1, string_2):
    if string_1.lower() == string_2.lower():
        if len(string_1) == # some value:
            return # do smth
        elif len(string_2) == # some value:
            return # do smth
    return # do smth
```

There's a main `if string_1.lower() == string_2.lower():` condition that prevents a nested block of code from running when `False`. So how can that code be written in a single `return ...` line? If can.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If only for the sake of doability, you can molest the ternary `x if y else z` operator:

```
return 1 if string_1.lower() != string_2.lower() else 2 if len(string_1) == 3 else 3 if len(string_2) == 4 else None
```

But in any serious production environment, your colleagues won't like you very much ;)

Comment: Thanks a lot for a comprehensible answer. You got my goal. I was interested in the right syntax and logic examination for things like this. This case of one-liner is obviously non-acceptable.